# Adding a edit field in a custom dialog in Installshield

Tags: app-config, installshield, customdialog

I have a setup project with Installshield Premium 2016.

I created a custom dialog that has a edit field. I created a property name which was named "CustomFields" and In my appconfig there is a key

```
    <add key="customFields" value="Test"></add>
```

So while installing the app, I want to it to change the value of customFields by user. My property value has a default name that is Test and in the installation dialog I can see this name

[image]

When I change this text by manually for example "Hello", after installation completed, in my appconfig i see "Test" value. It seems that it saves the default value. But as can be seen, the text field has referenced by this property thats why I can see the default value in my text field in the dialog.

I do not know where is the problem? I could not find also any documentation about custom edit fields.

I followed here a bit https://www.iwasdot.com/adding-a-custom-dialog-to-and-installshield-basic-msi-project/

but its a bit different and it did not work to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed @Michae's answer but still not worked. So I changed next pushbutton property and it worked finally..

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Private properties are not passed from the UI sequence to the execute sequence. If you want this to work, at a minumum you will have to rename your property to use only upper-case letters and underscores. (For example, change `CustomFields` to `CUSTOM_FIELDS`.) You may also have to include its name in the `SecureCustomProperties` property.